# Sorting FileHelpers data into different columns in SQl sever using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a code in C# which reads in delimited txt files, from multiple folders, parses through the data and then updates a Microsoft SQL server table with the correct values. Code shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace prototype_using_filehelpers
{


    class ManagerReport
    {

        [DelimitedRecord("|")]
        [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
        [IgnoreFirst()]


        public class ManagerReportNames
        {


            public int? MASTER_VALUE_ORDER;
            public int? MASTER_VALUE;
            public string RESORT;
            public int? CS_HEADING_COUNT_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ARR_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_DEP_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_NO_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_GUESTS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_TOTAL_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ROOM_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_INVENTORY_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_PERC_OCC_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_AVG_ROOM_RATE_MASTER;
            public int? LAST_YEAR_01;
            public int? SUB_GRP_1_ORDER;
            public string SUB_GRP_1;
            public string DESCRIPTION;
            public string AMOUNT_FORMAT_TYPE;
            public string PRINT_LINE_AFTER_YN;
            public int? HEADING_1_ORDER;
            public int? HEADING_1;
            [FieldOptional]
            public string HEADING_2;
            [FieldOptional]
            [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
            public decimal? SUM_AMOUNT;
            [FieldOptional]
            public decimal? FORMATTED_AMOUNT;


        }


        static void ProcessFilesCSVFiles(string copyPath, string destinationPath)
        {


            // first check if path exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(copyPath))
                // doesn't exist then exit, can't copy from something that doesn't exist
                return;
            var copyPathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(copyPath);
            // using the SearchOption.AllDirectories will search sub directories
            var copyPathCSVFiles = copyPathDirectory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            // loops through directory looking for txt files
            for (var i = 0; i < copyPathCSVFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                // get the file
                var csvFile = copyPathCSVFiles[i];
                //sets lines to the files full extention so it can then be called at a later time
                string lines = csvFile.FullName;

                // read the csv file line by line
                FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ManagerReportNames));
                var records = engine.ReadFile(lines) as ManagerReportNames[];


                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(record.RESORT);
                    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);



              // SQL connection. Creates connection and command and inserts the values taken from the File Helper engine into the SQL table
                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    SqlConnection conn;


                    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO test2 (property_id,val1) VALUES (@property_id,@val1)", conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property_id", record.RESORT);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }



                // creates a variable that combines the the directory of the new folder with the file name
                var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, csvFile.Name);
                // This loop prevents duplicates. If a file is already in the folder, it will delete the file already in there and move this one in.
                // Shouldn't be an issue since each file will have a different name
                if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(destinationFilePath);
                }
                // moves it to the new folder
                csvFile.MoveTo(destinationFilePath);


            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProcessFilesCSVFiles(@"C:\Users\Documents", @"C:\Users\Documents\Complete");


        }
    }
}
```

The code works but I'm trying to implement a new feature and I'm not sure how. Currently, it is updating the SQL server with two values: RESORT and FORMATTED_AMOUNT. RESORT is going into the table column "property_id" and FORMATTED_AMOUNT is going into val1. In my table I have also added val2, val3 and val4. HEADING_2 can have three different values, or be null. How would i fix my code so that when HEADING_2 is the first value, the corresponding FORMATTED_AMOUNT will go into val1 and when HEADING_2 is the second value, the corresponding FORMATTED_AMOUNT will go into v2 and when HEADING_2 is the third value, the corresponding FORMATTED_AMOUNT will go into val3 and finally when HEADING_2 is null, the corresponding FORMATTED_AMOUNT will go into val4

current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FileHelpers;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;

namespace prototype_using_filehelpers
{

    class ManagerReport
    {

        [DelimitedRecord("|")]
        [IgnoreEmptyLines()]
        [IgnoreFirst()]
        [IgnoreLast(2)]


        public class ManagerReportNames
        {


            public int? MASTER_VALUE_ORDER;
            public int? MASTER_VALUE;
            public string RESORT;
            public int? CS_HEADING_COUNT_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ARR_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_DEP_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_NO_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_GUESTS_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_TOTAL_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_ROOM_REVENUE_MASTER;
            public int? CS_FS_INVENTORY_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_PERC_OCC_ROOMS_MASTER;
            public int? CF_FS_AVG_ROOM_RATE_MASTER;
            public int? LAST_YEAR_01;
            public int? SUB_GRP_1_ORDER;
            public string SUB_GRP_1;
            public string DESCRIPTION;
            public string AMOUNT_FORMAT_TYPE;
            public string PRINT_LINE_AFTER_YN;
            public int? HEADING_1_ORDER;
            public int? HEADING_1;
            [FieldOptional]
            public string HEADING_2;
            [FieldOptional]
            [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")]
            public decimal? SUM_AMOUNT;
            [FieldOptional]
            public decimal? FORMATTED_AMOUNT;


        }

        static void ProcessFilesCSVFiles(string originalPath, string destinationPath)
        {


            // first check if path exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(originalPath))
                // doesn't exist then exit, can't copy from something that doesn't exist
                return;
            var copyPathDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(originalPath);
            // using the SearchOption.AllDirectories will search sub directories
            var copyPathCSVFiles = copyPathDirectory.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            // loops through directory looking for txt files
            for (var i = 0; i < copyPathCSVFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                // get the file
                var csvFile = copyPathCSVFiles[i];
                //sets lines to the files full extention so it can then be called at a later time
                string lines = csvFile.FullName;

                // read the csv file line by line
                FileHelperEngine engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(ManagerReportNames));
                var records = engine.ReadFile(lines) as ManagerReportNames[];


                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(record.RESORT);
                    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
                    // This allows us to split what column a row goes into based on whether it is a day month or year
                    string Heading = record.HEADING_2;
                    string Group = record.SUB_GRP_1;
                    string column;
                    if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC")
                    {
                        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC_WO_CH")
                    {
                        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM")
                    {
                        column = "ADR";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM_WO_CH")
                    {
                        column = "ADR_minus_Comp_and_House";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOMREV_AVL_ROOMS_MINUS_OOO")
                    {
                        column = "Revenue_per_Available_Room_minus_OOO";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "TOTAL_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Total_Revenue";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOM_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Room_Revenue";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "FOOD_BEV_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Food_And_Beverage_Revenue";
                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OTHER_REVENUE")
                    {
                        column = "Other_Revenue";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "PHYSICAL_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Total_Rooms_in_Hotel";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Rooms_Occupied";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_MINUS_COMP_HU")
                    {
                        column = "Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House_Use";

                    }
                    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "COMP_ROOMS")
                    {
                        column = "Complimentary_Rooms";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }



                    // SQL connection. Creates connection and command and inserts the values taken from the File Helper engine into the SQL table
                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    SqlConnection conn;


                    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
                    conn.Open();

                    //var sqlCommand2 = string.Format(@"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM[HEWreport] WHERE Property_ID = @Property_ID) INSERT INTO[HEWreport] (Property_ID, < ColumnName >) VALUES(@Property_ID, @val");
                    var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"MERGE [HEWreport] AS target USING (select @Property_ID as Property_ID, @val as {0}) AS source ON (target.Property_ID = source.Property_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0}
                                                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property_ID, {0}) VALUES (source.Property_ID, source.{0});", column);
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property_ID", record.RESORT);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }




                // creates a variable that combines the the directory of the new folder with the file name
                var destinationFilePath = Path.Combine(destinationPath, csvFile.Name);
                // This loop prevents duplicates. If a file is already in the folder, it will delete the file already in there and move this one in.
                // Shouldn't be an issue since each file will have a different name
                if (File.Exists(destinationFilePath))
                {
                    File.Delete(destinationFilePath);
                }
                // moves it to the new folder
                csvFile.MoveTo(destinationFilePath);


            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ProcessFilesCSVFiles(@"C:\Users\Documents\Hotels", @"C:\Users\Documents\Completed Hotels");


        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I changed up exactly what I want done but it's the same concept. Instead of the columns being val1 or val2 they are defined, I also needed more than what was in HEADING_2, I also needed SUB_GRP_1. I have also tried using parameters since I was also told AddWithValue() could cause issues but that still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a function that map HEADING_2 to the column name, like this

`var columnName = GetColumnNameFromHEADING_2(HEADING_2_value);`

you can change the code as the following:

```
var sqlCommand = string.Format("INSERT INTO test2 (property_id, {0}) VALUES (@property_id,@val)", columnName);
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@property_id", record.RESORT);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
```

If you want to combine rows as it is described in your comment use the merge statement:

```
    var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"
  MERGE [test2] AS target
                USING (select @property_id as property_id, @val as {0}) AS source
                ON (target.property_id = source.property_id)
                WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE
                SET {0}= source.{0}
                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                INSERT (property_id, {0}) 
                VALUES (source.property_id, source.{0});
", columnName);
```

Comment: Thank you. I added that to my code. I 'm just wondering if there is way so that when HEADING_2 is a 1 it goes into val1 and when HEADING_2 is a 2, it goes into that same row's val2. Because my rows go in a patter. It goes 1 then 2 then 3 for HEADING_2. It's usually not null. But those three HEADING_2's in a row are all related. I was just wondering if there was a way that those three rows could all be put in one table row with the value for FORMATTED_AMOUNT in the corresponding column

Comment: I keep getting this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: The parameterized query '(@Property_ID nvarchar(5),@val nvarchar(4000))MERGE [HEWrepor' expects the parameter '@val', which was not supplied.

Comment: Could you  provide the source code you have at the moment and the result of sqlCommand you formed? Check that you provide the parameter `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);`

Comment: I added my current code with what I am trying to fix. If i set val equal to a specific number, it works and prints that number in each column. It just won't work with printing the FORMATTED_AMOUNT. I also know that my file contains lines that have those exact parameters in them so it should return a value

Comment: so I was able to fix my problem. In my file I found that there were two lines that both contained the same HEADING_2 and the same SUB_GRP_1 except one of them was null and one had a value. i was able to fix this by just adding a parameter. My issue now is that it will only read in one line. So i can test my code the first time and it will work. However, it won't work again unless i go to my SQL table and delete that line and run it again. The goal is to upload multiple files at a time and put them all in a different row. I had implemented the reading in of multiple files and it still

Comment: does. It just only prints that one line to the SQL table, not all of them.

Comment: About the previous problem >the parameter '@val', which was not supplied
It is caused by the fact that sql expects DBNull.Value for null values. So, you may fix it but this expression group==null)?(object)DBNull.Value : (object) group.

Comment: Any idea about the new issue that I am having?

Comment: About for one-multiple lines - not sure I completely understand what you want. The current code maps all data to a record by its key (property_id). If you process multiple files that contain records with the same keys (property_id) as in the database they all update the same records in the database. If you want to update different records, you need to introduce an additional key field in your records. Let's call each file a batch, add BatchId to you records. For easy handling use GUID type for this field.

Comment: What I want to implement is a way that each txt file that comes in has its own row. The way that it currently is set up is great, but it only works for one txt file. Instead of updating the columns based on the next txt file, I want it to add a row and put the new values in a new row. Right now it will read in the txt and put the right numbers in the right columns. I just want it so that right after it puts them in the columns, it automatically makes a new row, and will put the new data coming in into the same columns in the same format but on a completely separate row